# How to access my riak-cs object from my browser

Tags: riak

I have setup my riak-cs storage. Everything is working well. I have also use erlcloud in creating and retrieving objects stored in riak-cs. However, I also want my riak objects to be accessible from the browser. I have tried **bucket-name.localhost:8080/key** and **localhost:8080/bucket-name/key** but no luck. Both returns

```
<Error>
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
 <Message>Access Denied</Message>
 <Resource>bucket-name/key</Resource>
 <RequestId/>
</Error>
```

The bucket do has public access control level so that it can be access without
authentication. Something is wrong.
 Can someone help me how to archive this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the public access control level of the object to `public_read` in erlcloud when storing it. At first I thought, all objects has the same **acl** level of their bucket.

`erlcloud_s3:put_object(Bucket, Key, Data, [{acl, public_read}], Headers, Config)`